# How to HTTP post nested Objects that are linked.( Node, RestAPI)

Tags: node.js, http, typescript, object

How do I post a linked object.
For example person creates a new  user , that automatically has a company + a department.  So When I do a post I actually posting a 3 separate objects

- Company Object that has an ID
- department object that parentID is companies ID
- User object that has an department id

so user linked to department, department linked to company.
All 3 objects have same structure. 
Please be aware this is an example of types. In my project the types are different, but logic stays the same, the are are linked.
Can't figure out the how to write the post .

```
[{
  id: 'xds1';
  name: 'Company X',
  parentId: 'xds1';
}, {
  id: 'xds2';
  name: 'department X',
  parentId: 'xds1';
}, {
  id: 'xds3';
  name: 'Roberto Tester',
  parentId: 'xds2';
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine what fields need to be supplied in the POST and what fields will be generated by the server.

I.E. as JSON POST body

```
{
  companyName: 'Company X',
  departmentName: 'Department X',
  userName: 'Roberto Tester'
}
```

which will create these three entities, generate unique IDs for each of them and assign those to the linked entities.

Comment: Is there a way you could update you answear with an example of how it could possibility look for "generate unique IDs for each of them and assign those to the linked entities". Can't figure out the logic

Comment: That totally depends on your stack. For example if you're using Node.js you can use [UUID](http://npm.im/uuid) to generate unique IDs. These can be used when writing to a database, first creating the Company, then the Department with the inclusion of the Company's ID, etc.